# Is there an offline browsable MS Office Support?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010

From a Google search I'm able to find How to [Insert headers and footers](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/word-help/insert-headers-and-footers-HP001226486.aspx?CTT=1#BM10). I'm impressed by the quality of the help. But instead of searching for something, I'm looking for a browsable form of this help?

**EDIT:**

By browsable, I mean offline help as shown:

[image]

There are lot of advantages with help in the above format. I don't like search interface.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Office-2007-Dummies-Wallace/dp/0470009233

Comment: Given that I can visit that page with my **browser**, it seems *browseable*. If you're looking for a version that can be used **offline**, please say so in your question.

Comment: I agree with @OliverSalzburg, if you are looking for an offline version of this help then harrymc's answer is good or you can use `HTTPTrack` to download the site for your offline browsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Office is shipped with offline help in compiled form, however starting with Office 2007 it's harder to find these files because they no longer use the .CHM format and instead have opted to use the newer form of compiled help, the [Microsoft Help 2 Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Help_2) (.HXS).

There are a collection of five files that make up the offline help for Microsoft Word:

- WINWORD.HXS
- WINWORD_COL.HXC
- WINWORD_COL.HXT
- WINWORD_F_COL.HXK
- WINWORD_K_COL.HXK

They can be found on disk where office is installed to, this is normally:

> Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\1033\

however the exact location may differ as some parts of that path may be different for each machine, for example if you are running 64bit OS then `Program Files` will be called `Program Files (x86)`, likewise the number after office will differ depending on the version of Office you have installed, in this case `Office12` refers to Office 2007.

Also it's useful to note that the help files for the other Microsoft Office products are found in the same location with a similar naming structure as shown above.

When it comes to view these files, more than likely your machine doesn't have a stand alone viewer installed already so you will need to download one first. I recommend downloading the [H2Viewer](http://helpware.net/mshelp2/h2viewer.htm) for free. Even more handy is when the H2Viewer is opened it brings up a list of already available HXS files on the machine which you should see the Word help file on that list already.

[image: H2Viewer Prompt]

Once the file is opened you are greeted with the full help content in offline form.

[image: H2Viewer Word Help]

Comment: 1. Can I copy these 5 files on to other system for viewing with H2Viewer? 2. Can I convert them to CHM?

Comment: @Claws, yes you can copy these files to any other machine for viewing. Regarding HXS to CHM conversion I found the following product on Google which might do the job, check it out: http://www.jsware.net/jsware/hxs2chm.php5

Comment: @Adam: Just want your confirmation on this: "These are _the five files_ that makeup all the _images and text_ in the documentation"

Comment: @Harrmc, I viewed this question and your answer when they were first posted, however I didn't re-read your answer after you made your edit with the similar information so therefore did not refer to it when I was formulating my answer. In any case your answer is correct as well so I have given it an upvote.

Comment: @claws, yes that is correct, all of the help content is contained within those five files.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use Word 2010 help in offline mode :

1. Call up the Help window (for example by using F1)
2. Click at the bottom on "Connected to Office.com"
3. Choose "Show content only from this computer"

[image]

Office help in the later versions is no longer available in compiled-help (.chm) format,
but rather in [Microsoft Help 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Help_2) (.hxs or .hxn) format.

Setting Microsoft Help to Offline ensures that these help files are put on your computer, although normally they should already be there in the directory
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Help`.

If you do not like the Microsoft new viewer user-interface, although similar in functionality to the old one, you could use another free viewer such as [H2Viewer](http://www.helpware.net/mshelp2/h2viewer.htm),
offering a more classical interface,
and choose from the offered list of help files (for Office 2010)
the file named `MS.WINWORD.14.1033` :

[image]

Comment: Kindly look at the edit.

Comment: I have also added an edit above.

Answer (score -1):

The [official Microsoft Office website](http://office.microsoft.com) may surely be useful to you, especially [its support pages](http://office.microsoft.com/support/).

Comment: Hello air-dex, claws is already aware of this site (check his link) and apparently not satisfied cause its not *browsable*. I assume he means something similar to index of the integrated [office F1 offline help](http://oldsite.soziologie-blossfeld.de/courses/JanSkopek-PCPTFSW/modul-I-Dateien/image056.jpg).

Comment: @air-dex: As the above comment says, I'm looing for _browsable_ form of that website.